# I'm Getting an ApiError while using dropbox as a django storage

Tags: python, django, django-templates, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm using dropbox as a django storage to serve media files and while uploading to dropbox all working fine the files are uploading to the root directory as expected but the uploaded image won't render on the templates,

The error that showing

```
ApiError at /index
ApiError('304328f4c8384ce99352fc8e9c338f71', GetTemporaryLinkError('path', LookupError('not_found', None)))
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/index
Django Version: 3.1.2
Exception Type: ApiError
Exception Value:    
ApiError('304328f4c8384ce99352fc8e9c338f71', GetTemporaryLinkError('path', LookupError('not_found', None)))
Exception Location: /home/raam124/.local/share/virtualenvs/rattota-GtEiaCOf/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dropbox/dropbox.py, line 337, in request
Python Executable:  /home/raam124/.local/share/virtualenvs/rattota-GtEiaCOf/bin/python
Python Version: 3.8.5
Python Path:    
['/home/raam124/Documents/rattota',
 '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/home/raam124/.local/share/virtualenvs/rattota-GtEiaCOf/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 23 Oct 2020 10:02:16 +0000
```

my static and media files setting

```
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media"),
]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_cdn')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media_cdn')
```

my dropbox storage settings

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.dropbox.DropBoxStorage'

DROPBOX_OAUTH2_TOKEN = 'token here'

DROPBOX_ROOT_PATH = '/'
```

and I'm rendering the image using

```
<img alt="" class="card-img img-fluid geeks" src="{{topstory.image.url}}" />
```

Comment: You might be trying to access a file that has been deleted/ doesn't exist, asked [here](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-API-Support-Feedback/Strange-python-API-error/td-p/234046)

Answer (score 0):

Specify the full path (display path) to download or access any file from DROPBOX

Answer (score 0):

As Decoy mentioned... you may need to adjust your
settings.py --
STATIC_URL and MEDIA_URL to be the url of its location on dropbox's domain.

example:
STATIC_URL = 'https//dropbox.com/user/staticfile'